# RStudio - LD_PREOAD Issue

Tags: r, rodbc, rstudio-server, ld-preload

I get a RDOBC error in RStudio that does not occur when I use R on the server itself.

R -

```
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31) -- "Pumpkin Helmet"
Copyright (C) 2014 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

library(RODBC)
conn = odbcConnect("Cloudera_HIVE64", uid="manishm", pwd="tdpass")
data = sqlQuery(conn,"SELECT * from default.test")
data
[1] test.id test.name
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

RStudio -

```
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31) -- "Pumpkin Helmet"
Copyright (C) 2014 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

library(RODBC)
conn = odbcConnect("ClouderaHIVE64", uid="manishm", pwd="tdpass")
Warning messages:
1: In odbcDriverConnect("DSN=ClouderaHIVE64;UID=manishm;PWD=tdpass") :
[RODBC] ERROR: state HY000, code 11560, message [unixODBC][Cloudera]ODBC Unable to locate SQLGetPrivateProfileString function.
2: In odbcDriverConnect("DSN=Cloudera_HIVE64;UID=manishm;PWD=tdpass") :
ODBC connection failed
```

I have checked the environment variables and have ensured that the below are correct for all users

```
ODBCINI=/opt/cloudera/hiveodbc/Setup/odbcinst.ini 
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib64/libodbcinst.so
```

Any idea why this will work in R and not in RStudio with the same environment settings?

Answer (score 0):

I once had a similar problem on ubuntu 12.04 that I could solve, but it was kind of hacky. For reasons I don't understand, it seems that environment variables are sometimes not passed to applications that are started by clicking on the launcher. The problem that I had concerned another package, but the symptoms were similar: a properly defined environment variable seemed to be unknown to RStudio.

From this experience, I suggest the following:

1. Open a linux shell and change directory to `cd /usr/share/applications`
2. Type `sudo cp rstudio.desktop rstudio.desktop.bak` to create a backup copy of this file which we will modify.
3. Edit rstudio.desktop as sudo with your favorite text editor, like `sudo gedit rstudio.desktop`
4. The second line after `[Desktop Entry]` probably contains something like `Exec=/usr/lib/rstudio/bin/rstudio %F`. Change this line so that the required environment variables are explicitly passed, e.g., `Exec=sh -c 'env LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib64/libodbcinst.so /usr/lib/rstudio/bin/rstudio %F'`
5. Close RStudio and try to start again; possibly after rebooting.
6. If you experience any problem launching RStudio after these modifications, restore the previous version of the file `rstudio.desktop` with `cd /usr/share/applications` followed by `cp -f rstudio.desktop.bak rstudio.desktop`. This should restore the initial state. It means that your problem wasn't soved, but at least no harm should be done.

Hope this helps. Wishing you good luck...